# What can i change in this HTML or CSS code to achieve the desktop design that i wanted?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to achieve this [image] desktop design.

The mobile design has been completed but when I try changing the mobile design to desktop design, I am using a specific flex property row-reverse. When I use the row-reverse property the result looks like this
[image]

I am unable to figure out how to fix the position to achieve the desktop design and have been stuck on this problem for the past few days.

Could someone please tell me what am i doing wrong and how do i fix this issue.

```css
@import url('css-reset.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');

:root {
    --color-main-background: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
    --color-card-background: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
    --color-soft-voilet: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);
    --color-white-main: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --color-white-paragraph: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
    --color-white-stats: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);
    --font-weight-four: 400;
    --font-weight-seven: 700;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-main-background);
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
    color: var(--color-white-main);
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-height: 750px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* padding: 0 2rem; */
    background-color: var(--color-card-background);
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* .main-img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
} */

picture>* {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.img-component {
    position: relative;
}

.img-component::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%, 0.5);
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.main-header {
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca',
        sans-serif;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: var(--color-white-main);
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.insight {
    color: var(--color-soft-voilet)
}

.h1-first,
.h1-second {
    display: block;
}

.stats,
.heading {
    display: block;
}

.paragraph {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.para-1,
.para-2,
.para-3,
.para-4 {
    font-family: 'Inter',
        sans-serif;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    color: var(--color-white-paragraph);
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.75;
}

.stats {
    color: var(--color-white-main);
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-seven);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.heading {
    font-family: 'Inter',
        sans-serif;
    font-weight: var(--font-weight-four);
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: var(--color-white-stats);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    body {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        min-height: 400px;
        max-width: 50rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    picutre {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    picture>* {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    }

    .img-component {
        position: relative;
    }

    .img-component::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: hsl(277, 64%, 61%, 0.5);
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Stats preview card component</title>

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-component">
      <picture>
        <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/images/image-header-desktop.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 100px)" srcset="/images/image-header-mobile.jpg">
        <img class="main-img" src="/images/image-header-mobile.jpg" alt="main image">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="main-header">
      <h1><span class="h1-main"> Get <span class="insight">insights</span> that</span>
        <span class="h1-first">help your business</span>
        <span class="h1-second"> grow.</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraph">
      <p>
        <span class="para-1"> Discover the benefits of data</span>
        <span class="para-2">analytics and make better decisions</span>
        <span class="para-3">regarding revenue, customer</span>
        <span class="para-4">experience, and overall efficiency.</span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-heading">
      <span class="stats">10k+</span>
      <span class="heading">COMPANIES</span>
      <span class="stats">314</span>
      <span class="heading">TEMPLATES</span>
      <span class="stats">12M+</span>
      <span class="heading">QUERIES</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: flex-direction: column

Comment: @BernardBorg flex-direction column didn't worked

Comment: flex-direction: column should get your div items stacked vertically.

Comment: @BernardBorg using column just increased the size of my mobile design. It didnt changed into the desktop design i wanted. The mobile design size just went bigger.  https://ibb.co/kSR0HnP like this

Comment: Add an image of your mobile design to the question

Comment: @BernardBorg Here is the link: https://ibb.co/FX0DzgL

Comment: flex-direction column won't work unless you wrap your `.main-header`, `.paragraph` and `.stat-heading` into a parent div, and then you change the related style in order to match your image example, you will also need to wrap the `.stats` and `heading` into a parent div, so you will have 3 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help to restructure your section.

I basically tried to roughly replicate your design using a slightly different approach:

So given the main div (container), let's split it in half creating 2 child div into it, aligning them with d-flex applied to the container.
Into the left one, let's create 2 other divs: one which will contain the header and paragraph and the other which will contain the 3 stats and heading. I will then suggest to wrap each stats and heading into they own div, this will help you to correctly align them on desktop and mobile using d-flex, and related flex-directions.

```css
    html,
        body {

            height: 100%;
        }

        div {
            border: 2px solid red
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .box-left {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: blueviolet;
            height: 500px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;


        }

        .box-right {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: brown;
            height: 500px;
            width: 50%;
            background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184360/pexels-photo-3184360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1);
            background-size: cover;

        }

        .box-bottom {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .text-wrapper {
            padding: 50px;
        }


        @media (max-width:768px) {
            .container {
                flex-direction: column-reverse;

            }

            .box-left,
            .box-right {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .box-left {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .box-bottom {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-left">
            <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div>
                    <h1>Your title here</h1>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page
                        when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal
                        distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                        readable English.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="box-bottom">
                    <div>
                        <h2>10k</h2>
                        <p>SOMETHING</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>10k</h2>
                        <p>SOMETHING</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>10k</h2>
                        <p>SOMETHING</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-right">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, a code-only answer can be made much more useful to readers if it has some verbal desription of what has been changed/added

Comment: @AHaworth hello, i tried using row reverse which is not going as what i expected.

Comment: Explanation added above, I also added a red border in order to make the structure a bit more clear. Hope it will help